# The File Encoding Is utf8 but is in Windows-1256 readable

Tags: encoding, utf-8

I am working on files with unknown encoding at first but I get the encoding with this lines in JAVA:

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("D:\\lbl2\\1 (26).LBL"));
    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(in);
    System.out.print(inputStreamReader.getEncoding());
```

and we get UTF8 in output. 
but the problem is that when I try to see file content with the browser or text editor like Notpad++ I can't see character correctly. Instead when I change the encoding to Windows-1256 all of characters view correct and readable.
Do i do any mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java does not attempt to detect the encoding of a file. `getEncoding` returns the encoding that was selected in the `InputStreamReader` constructor. If you don't use one of the constructors that take a character set parameter, you get the 'platform default charset', according to Oracle's documentation.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9312816/java-platforms-default-charset-on-different-platforms) discusses what the platform default charset is, and how you can change it.

If you know in advance that this file is Windows-1256, you can use:

```
InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(in, "Windows-1256");
```

Attempting to detect the encoding of a file usually fails - see for example the [Bush hid the facts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bush_hid_the_facts) issue in Windows Notepad.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no 100% reliable way to detect the encoding of a file and as the other answer points out Java by default doesn't try. It simply assumes the platform's default encoding.

If you know the files are all in a single encoding then great, you can just specify that encoding and life is good.

If you know that some files are in UTF-8 and some files are in a single legacy encoding then you can generally get away with trying a strict* UTF-8 decode first. If the strict UTF-8 decode errors out then you move on to your legacy encoding.

If you have a wider mix of encodings things get considerablly harder, you may have to resort to some quite complex language processing to sort them out.

* I belive to get a strict decode in Java you need to first get the "Charset", then get a "CharsetDecoder" and then use the "onMalformedInput" method to set it to strict mode.