# Encoding error - unmappable character for encoding ASCII

Tags: java, zxing

I'm having some trouble compiling the ZXing source code on a headless Ubuntu 16.04 server, while at home on Ubuntu 18.04 (non-headless) it compiles just fine. I've tinkered around with locales, making sure they're identical, though it doesn't fix the errors like there:

[ERROR] /root/zxing/core/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/result/WifiResultParser.java:36: error: unmappable character for encoding ASCII

[image]
Having gone through setup-locale and other few attempts with LC_ALL I just don't understand what the issue may be, and changing the original code is the least favorable option. This is, file -bi reports the files being as text/plain; charset=utf-8, so I'm stumped where ASCII comes into play.

**For now I can do with mvn package -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true but that's just a workaround, not a solution.**

Further tests with java -jar -verbose suggests there may be something more serious that's missing, because it stops executing at:

[6.979s][info][classload] java.time.Instant source: jrt:/java.base
[6.980s][info][classload] java.time.Clock source: jrt:/java.base
[6.980s][info][classload] java.time.Clock$SystemClock source: jrt:/java.base
[6.982s][info][classload] java.time.ZoneId source: jrt:/java.base
[6.982s][info][classload] java.time.ZoneOffset source: jrt:/java.base

On my local machine it initializes the java.util.logging.Logger after this line, while on the server it skips past it and exits.

Further inspection shows that it fails to read the image I'm giving to it stopping at:
[Dynamic-linking native method com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readImage ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.disposeReader ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.io.FileInputStream.close0 ... JNI]

Comment: Looking at the source code of `WifiResultParser`: the Javadoc contains the German author name "Steffen Kieß", which perhaps causes encoding trouble. You should check whether the actual encoding of the source code is UTF-8 or not. I'd use a hex editor by the way.

Comment: Of course I've seen that, but as I mentioned on my local machine it compiles fine with default settings after cloning from the repository, and I'm trying to figure out what is missing on the headless server.

Comment: Very well, I was just checking. Perhaps m4gic's answer will solve it.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the default encoding, which is not [necesary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9312816/java-platforms-default-charset-on-different-platforms) UTF-8 
Please give a try to the following:

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```