# How do I find and use every Java supported platform default charset?

Tags: java

I am working on a project that deals with security (blockchain) and it makes use of the `String.getBytes()` function. This function has undefined behavior based on which "platform default charset" is used.

Because of this and other reasons, I would like to test the program's continuous integration using every possible platform default charset.

The project supports Java version 11+.

How do I find the list of every possible platform default charset?

And how do I run Java in that charset (using any means possible) in order to run my tests?

Comment: [A quick google for the latter question about setting the default charset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361975/setting-the-default-java-character-encoding)

Comment: If you don't like the fact that it uses the default charset, just pass in a specific charset! It will use that one!

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9312816/platforms-default-charset-on-different-platforms) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361975/setting-the-default-java-character-encoding/) help?

Comment: Wrong question. Don't ask how to test all combinations of "*undefined* behavior", instead ask how to make the code have "*well-defined* behavior". --- *Hint:* Sweeper already gave [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66344716/how-do-i-find-and-use-every-java-supported-platform-default-charset#comment117291780_66344716) for that.

Comment: Yes! Fixing the UB is desirable. And I do see the `getBytes` alternative with specified `Charset`. However, at present this is a matter of leadership, across the project I'm in as well as all its dependencies. If I can prove that a tangible problem exists (using a failed test case) then I get resources to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to run Java with a different "platform default charset".

```sh
java -D"file.encoding=UTF-16" -jar ...
```

Here is the list of all possible platform default charsets:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html

*P.S. The "platform" default charset sounds like an immutable value compiled into Java on your computer. It's not. This is something you can change at VM execution time.*